# How to add link fields to serializer dynamically

Tags: python, django, serialization

I would like to create a general serializer for a ManyToMany link, which will include linked models data.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

def get_model_serializer(model, fields_to_serialize):

    class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = model
            fields = fields_to_serialize
    return BaseSerializer

def get_many_to_many_serializer(many_to_many_model, first_model, second_model, fields_to_serialize)

    serializer = get_model_serializer(many_to_many_model, fields_to_serialize)

    class BaseSerializer(serializer):
        pass
        # only when I directly set the attributes upon class definition it works
        #attendee = get_model_serializer(first_model)()
        #operation = get_model_serializer(second_model)()

    # This does not work
    setattr(BaseSerializer, first_model.__name__.lower(), get_model_serializer(first_model)())
    setattr(BaseSerializer, second_model.__name__.lower(), get_model_serializer(second_model)())

    #Or this
    #setattr(BaseSerializer, 'operation', get_model_serializer(first_model)())
    #setattr(BaseSerializer, 'attendee', get_model_serializer(second_model)())
    return BaseSerializer
```

The problem is, that when I set the attribute using setattr, the linked models are not serialized. I guess there is some magic upon class creation or whatever?

Any ideas, how can I go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the three argument form of [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to dynamically create new types/classes

```
type('M2MSerializer', (serializer, ), {
    first_model.__name__.lower(): get_model_serializer(first_model)(),
    first_model.__name__.lower(): get_model_serializer(first_model)()
})
```

Comment: `serializer` is the return value from your call to `get_model_serializer`?

Comment: You are probably reacting to my deleted comment - I was just calling it `type('M2MSerializer', serializer,...` - without touple in the second argument, which was obviously wrong